# How to save streaming videos in Android by saving to SDcard?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I need to stream videos from an URL and then i want to save the video to SDcard.

Answer (score 3):

For video streaming take a look at the following example/projects:
[Audio and Video on Android- Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)
[Vidtry an Open Source Project by Mark Murphy](http://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry/tree/master/src/com/commonsware/)
[Video Streaming Example by Davanum(this might be out of date)](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/)

Saving to SDcard: I am not very sure, but once you have the video stream(abstracted as InputStream) in your code you should be able to save it on SD card using normal File I/O operations.

Comment: Will textView.setVisibility(View.GONE) help?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when you prepare your videos for streaming. The documentation on the MediaPlayer class says it is accepting video streaming over HTTP only if the following 2 conditions are true:

1. The 'moov' atom has to be before the 'mdat' atom.
2. The clip has to be reasonably interleaved.

While the first condition is quite straightforward, about the 2nd one I couldn't find a definitive answer on what does it mean for a clip to be "reasonably interleaved".